# duplicate grouped state and bind to onChange event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

How can I make dynamic row (add and delete row), and input binding (bind onChange event) 
to work?, If it's just single input then it's easy, but a certain structure to defined 
the intial form element.

```
this.state = {
  rowCount: 1,
  rows: [{
    id: 1,
    structure: [
      {
        type: 'input',
        value
      },
      {
        type: 'textarea',
        value: 
      }
    ]
  }]
}

render() {
    return(
      <div>{this.state.rows.map(o => <div>
        {o.structure.map(s => {
          let block = ''
          if(s.type === 'input') {
            block = <div><input /></div>
          }else if(s.type === 'textarea') {
            block = <div><textarea /></div>
          }
          return block
        })}
        <button onClick={this.addBlock}>Add block</button>
      </div>)}</div>
    )
  }
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/nr88plwqj4

Comment: what do you want to do when user clickt addBlock button what do you want to add at that time?

Comment: @ShivaSai clone the entire row (input and textarea)

Comment: do you mean when the users clicks add button he should get an another input filed and textarea? am i right

Comment: The snipped fails in the addBlock definition. you might want to rewrite it as "addblock() {}"

Comment: I assume that the structure is the same for each block added using "addBlock"? that is, using an input and a textarea

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code so we can add blocks (delete have a similar approach), with the asumption that all the blocks will have the same structure. Also, I split your "render" in several "renders" that display different parts of the program, to make it easier to read.

https://codesandbox.io/s/xjzlzqj04z

The idea is the following: Everytime you click to Add block, you check all the rows, making a copy into a "newRows" variable. Finnaly, I do a push to newRows with the new data we want to add, in this case and adding the suitable id.

In the case of this structure in particular, I highly recommend that each row is a separate react component, more if the structure is the same for each row (text + input). If you do it with an extra react component, you can manage the add or delete block with the state being a simple array of ids instead of adding all the structure, and all the and all the logic (onchange value, delete) can be manage inside the other component. If you want to access to the value of all the components in the base component, you can add as a prop an "updateValue" that will get the id, and will update the state. I will try to make an example and update it later

edit:
here I have an example with the rows added as a different component. This simplify a lot the state logic, but that also depends on your needs.

https://codesandbox.io/s/4xq4w37v1w

I must say, codesandbox is a bit buggy with react, so If it doesnt work I recomend to "select all -> cut -> paste"

Comment: hmm onChange doesn't work, that's the biggest challenge there

Comment: codesandbox is a bit buggy, and onChange works when it feels like it - same with this.setState, so try it in a real react enviroment and tell me if it works there.

Comment: it doesn't make sense, codesanbox doesn't have bug, it's your code problem for sure.

Comment: I check it in a new react project, and it do have the same error with the onChange. I'll take a look to it and I will fix it later.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I did the onChange handlers as if the parameter was the input value, however it is not, its wrapper and should be handled in the following way: param.target.value. I just assumed that it was a codesandbox error because it did not detected the setState unless I did a total refresh when working in the code, so I though it was a similar issue. Reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example of adding new row and deleting the last row without changing the initial state rows object structure:

https://codesandbox.io/s/vm4lqnjyz7

A few points worth to be mentioned:

1) don't forget to add keys to elements when rendering a list, here's an explanation why: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

2) "rowCount" state property seems to be redundant as it equals the rows array length

3) "add row" button probably should be placed outside of the map method if you're going just to add a new row to existing array (instead of building an independent tree of input blocks inside each box).